# Java Clean String?

Tags: java, string, sockets, tcp

So I'm working with TCP and I got the data from DataInputStream, however when I get the data it has stuff like ^X^@^E^R around it. When it shouldn't do. Is there anyway I can remove this. It would need to be dynamic though.

```
DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

StringBuffer inputLine = new StringBuffer();
String tmp;

while((tmp = dataIn.readLine()) != null){
    //tmp = Normalizer.normalize(tmp, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

    inputLine.append(tmp);
    logText(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Probably data encoding or stream reading problem?

Comment: It gets the data, its just the data is inbetween stuff like that.

Comment: post your code formated in your question pls

Comment: Have you read the API documentation of DataInputStream?

Comment: you're doing an assignment and a comparison on the same line - thats "bad code" and will break functionality at some point - in fact in quite a few languages this loop will run forever since an assignment is always `!= null` - if that works in java your whole application depends on the farsightedness of JRE/JDK developers.

Comment: Not related to the question, but looks like you'd better use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @specializt the code is fine, and will never break. It has nothing to do with JRE/JDK developers (unless they have not done their job correctly). This syntax is part of the JLS. Some don't like it for *style*, but that is the only issue one could have with it.

Comment: Do you want to remove all "control characters" from the string?

Comment: @Bohemian id like to to see the exact part of JLS in which it is explicitly stated that an assignment / comparison combo is valid

Comment: @specializt it has nothing to do with "assignment comparison combo". The result of an assignment is the assigned value. If you chose to then compare it so be it. But you could also do something else with it, like `list.add(v = x);` to assign x to v and add x to a list. You must put brackets around the assignment to compare it because assignment has the lowest operator precedence. This kind of code is generally frowned upon because it isn't as clear as when coded as separate operations... but it works.

Comment: @Bohemian You are avoiding my request. In fact i know have found evidence for my claim "bad code" in JLS (7) itself : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html, section 15.7 - even in the JSL itself such code is _not_ recommended as quite a lot of "side effects" may appear in an unwanted order - additionally, return values of methods may even be *discarded* altogether (section 15.1), effectively _breaking functionality_. As far as im concerned : qed, have a nice evening.

Comment: @specializt https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26 `At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred.` Remember what I told you about toning down the combativeness?

Comment: @specializt As for the recommendation you refer to, that's just that: a recommendation. And it's a good one as code with fewer side effects is more readable. But it isn't "bad code" in the sense that it might break at any future point. In any case, it doesn't even refer to this scenario.

Comment: @specializt Even in the section you quoted, it only states that it "MAY appear in unwanted order", which can be bypassed with proper use of brackets.

Comment: @biziclop `An expression statement that is a method invocation may also invoke a method that produces a result; in this case the value returned by the method is quietly discarded` and `It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification. Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right evaluation of expressions.` Now :  remember how i didnt care what random people on the internet want me to do?

Comment: @specializt Maybe you should since both your quotes expose your complete lack of understanding. The first one is about using a method as an expression statement without storing its value (e.g. calling `it.next();` to discard the first element of an iterator), the second one talks about not relying on the order of evaluation in terms of side effects (e.g. exceptions) and using parentheses to make evaluation order clear. (Or alternatively, breaking it up into multiple expressions.)

Comment: @user3642449 We should really see the other end of the connection too, the code that writes the data you're trying to read here.

Answer (score 1):

`DataInputStream.readLine()` is deprecated. Use a BufferedReader instead.

eg: 
`BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));`

How I read lines:

```
while ((socket != null) && !(socket.isClosed())) {
    // read in a line but only if there is one - blocks here till there is a line

    String clientSentence = input.readLine();

    if ((clientSentence != null) && (!(clientSentence.equals("")))) {
         // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, however it still gives the same text back.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem when using my method to read lines. Seems to work just fine for me...

Comment: So same code just change "  DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());" to what you put correct?

Comment: More or less, yea. If you're still getting the weird data you should probably check where you're sending the data as well. @user3642449 I've edited in how I'm reading input.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all control characters (those bytes below decimal 32), you can do this:

```
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("[\000-\01F]", "");
```